# Which data type should I use to handle nine-digit account numbers and why?

Tags: c#, sql, database, informix

Which data type should I use to handle *9-digit account numbers* and why?

`varchar(9)` or `int` or `decimal` or something else ?

I'm talking from a database perspective  — and the DBMS is Informix.

Comment: If you're only interested in the database side, why include the C# tag? It looks like the `INTEGER` type should be fine - it handles  -2,147,483,647 to +2,147,483,647, so that includes all 9-digit numbers...

Comment: Are the account numbers always exactly 9 digits or do you need to store both `0035` and `000000035`?

Comment: @JonSkeet : i'm interested in the logic, the asp.net application should use data like this , could you recommend a specific type please?

Comment: Well I've suggested the `INTEGER` type already. (And that would correspond to `int` in C#...) As Lasse asks, do you need to be able to differentiate between "0035" and "000000035"? If so, you shouldn't use a numeric type at all, probably.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen :always 9 digits and i put a validation to force the user to input just 9 digits

Comment: OK, then go with what @JonSkeet suggested.

Comment: If the length is fixed I would consider `char(9)` instead of some numeric type (mostly as the digits doesn't represent a number that you can do any meaningful arithmetic on - this is just a personal preference though).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Does the int in db suit nine digits ?

Comment: Fixed char, with insert/update triggers to verify that the format is always correct!

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/informix/data-types) the `INTEGER` data type supports the range of +/- 2^31, which is, as @JonSkeet says, 2,147,483,647, so yes, this supports 9 digit numbers. Do note that you will have to pad the number with zeroes, since if you store `000000035`, and read it back it will be just `35` since numerically these are the same value. In this case, however, I think perhaps you should go with `CHAR(9)` since this isn't really a number, you're not going to do any arithmetic with it, it's more like a unique code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use `CHAR(9)`.

You have a number of options, most of them mentioned in the comments.  The options have different trade-offs.  They include:

- `CHAR(9)`.  This uses 9 bytes of storage, but can store leading zeros and that can save on formatting in the applications.  You can write a check constraint that ensures that the value always contains 9 digits.  If you later need to use longer numbers, you can extend the type easily to `CHAR(13)` or `CHAR(16)` or whatever.
- `INTEGER`.  This uses 4 bytes of storage.  If you need leading zeros, you will have to format them yourself.  If you later need more digits, you will need to change the type to `BIGINT`.
- `SERIAL`.  This could be used on one table and would automatically generate new values when you insert a zero into the column.  Cross-referencing tables would use the `INTEGER` type.
- `DECIMAL(9,0)`.  This uses 5 bytes of storage, and does not store leading zeros so you will have to format them yourself.  If you later need more digits, you can change the type to `DECIMAL(13,0)` or `DECIMAL(16,0)` or whatever.
- `BIGINT` and `BIGSERIAL`.  These are 8-byte integers that can take you to 16 digits without problem.  You have to provide leading zeros yourself.
- `INT8` and `SERIAL8` — do not use these types.
- `VARCHAR(9)`.  Not really appropriate since the length is not variable.  It would require 10 bytes on disk where 9 is sufficient.
- `LVARCHAR(9)`.  This is even less appropriate than `VARCHAR(9)`.
- `NCHAR(9)`.  This could be used as essentially equivalent to `CHAR(9)`, but if you're only going to store digits, you may as well use `CHAR(9)`.
- `NVARCHAR(9)`.  Not appropriate for the same reasons that `VARCHAR(9)` and `NCHAR(9)` are not appropriate.
- `MONEY(9,0)`. Basically equivalent to `DECIMAL(9,0)` but might attract currency symbols — it would be better to use `DECIMAL(9,0)`.

Any other type is rather quickly inappropriate, unless you design an extended type that uses `INTEGER` for storage but provides a conversion function to `CHAR(9)` that adds the leading zeros.